# Однородные члены предложения

Tags: синтаксис

А здесь точно 2 ряда однородных членов:

"В ней он хочет выразить не только чувства, но и всю любовь к родному краю, к неброской прелести русской природы".

"К краю", "к прелести природы" - это одн. чл. второй группы, относятся к слову "любовь", а любовь - это тоже одн. чл. Какая схема будет здесь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*В ней он хочет выразить (что?) **чувства, любовь*** -- однородные дополнения, соединённые союзом "не только…, но и…"

*Любовь (к чему? какую?)  **к краю, к прелести*** -- однородные дополнения с определительным оттенком.

===

Гм... Похоже, здесь ***к краю, к прелести*** не только к ***любви*** относятся, а являются дополнениями и к ***чувствам:***

*чувства (к чему? какие?) **к краю, к прелести.***

Answer (score 0):

Но фраза ужас какая корявая... "Не только чувства, но и любовь" — этта што?! Да и "неброская прелесть природы" очень сомнительна...

Comment: Niemand: "Но фраза ужас какая корявая... "Не только чувства, но и любовь" — этта што?!"=== И я этого противопоставления не понимаю. Чушь какая-то! Но...